# Is it possible to open a user's default email with an attachment on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want a user of my iOS app to be able to send an email with their default email app (chosen in settings in iOS 14+) with a dynamically generated attachment. We currently use MFMailComposeViewController, which can attach our file, but cannot use the user's default email app. The standard way to use a user's default email app seems to be using a "mailto" URL, but there does not seem to be a way to include an attachment.

Is this impossible to do both because of security or some other reason? Or is there some workaround I can implement?

Comment: Just a guess, but the good news is that is't *not* simply security - but maybe it should be. Here's the bad news, Apple controls certain things - and for quite a long time in iOS it also included the default email app - but how would you expect them to build an API (with security) that a third party email app could use for this?

Comment: What is your topic about?  The title says that you want to open a mail message with an attachment.  But you then state that you want your users to send a message with an attachment.  Which is it?

Comment: @El Tomato the user clicks a button that opens the mail app so they can compose an email to send to us. It auto-populates the recipient, topic, and automatically attaches a file. They do not open anyone else's message.